# directive not showing template properly in AngularJS Bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-4

I am using a custom directive to dynamically generate two columns in a row. Using just Bootstrap, I am able to get the design I want, it is seen below with html code.

[image: It works]

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-6 border border-dark d-none d-md-block">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="pics/apple.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 align-self-center">
            <ul>
                <li>Name:APPLE</li>
                <li>Dimensions:THIS ONE</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now when I use a custom directive with the template having the same exact HTML structure, it looks like this:
[image: It does not work anymore using directives]

HTML:

```
<features pics="pics/apple.png" name="Iphone" dimensions="One"></features>
```

AngularJS:

```
app.directive('features',function(){
    var direc={};
    var link=function(scope,element,attributes){
        scope.pics=attributes["pics"];
        scope.name=attributes["name"];
        scope.dimensions=attributes["dimensions"];
    }
    direc.restrict="AE";
    direc.link=link;
    direc.template='<div class="col-md-6 border border-dark d-none d-md-block"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-6"><img class="img-fluid" src="{{pics}}" /></div><div class="col-md-6 align-self-center"><ul><li>Name:{{name}}</li><li>Dimensions:{{dimensions}}</li></ul></div></div></div>';
    direc.scope={};
    return direc;
})
```

Any idea why it does so? Thank you for reading.

Comment: What happens if you use ng-src for your directive instead of src? Ng-src makes sure the image isn't rendered until angularjs has had a chance to interpolate its value. I have a hunch that since you're just using src, the css is sizing up against the broken image first instead of the actual image. It would help if you posted a plunkr so we could play around with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between the initial Bootstrap template and the `features` directive is that the directive template is surrounded by the `<features>` tag.

I guess the tag has CSS attributes that make it looks different.

In the example below I added the style `display: inline-block` on the second feature tag and I get the same rendering as you.

Another possibility is that the CSS styles of the component inherits those of a parent component, for example a Bootstrap column

Here's an sample snippet to illustrate this

**Important:**
Run the Snippet and click The **Full page** link on the top right corner or you won't see images

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app', []);

    angular
        .module('app')
        .directive('features', function () {
            return {
                restrict: 'AE',
                scope: {},
                template: '<div class="col-md-6 border border-dark d-none d-md-block"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-6"><img class="img-fluid" src="{{pics}}" /></div><div class="col-md-6 align-self-center"><ul><li>Name:{{name}}</li><li>Dimensions:{{dimensions}}</li></ul></div></div></div>',
                link: link
            };

            function link(scope, element, attributes) {

                scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
                    // destroy events binded to $rootScope, 
                    // cancel $interval and $timeout timers
                });

                scope.pics = attributes["pics"];
                scope.name = attributes["name"];
                scope.dimensions = attributes["dimensions"];
            }
        });

    angular
        .module('app')
        .filter('excludedItemsFilter', function () {
            return function (items, excludedStatus) {
                excludedStatus = excludedStatus || 'disabled'; // default value
                return items.filter(function (item) {
                    return item
                        && item.status !== excludedStatus;
                });
            }
        });

})();
```

```css
.my-features {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      class="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h5>Initial Bootstrap template</h3>
    <div class="col-md-6 border border-dark d-none d-md-block">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <img
            class="img-fluid"
            src="https://dpyxfisjd0mft.cloudfront.net/lab9-2/system/resized/Shop/Productpages%20-%2010092019/iPhone%2011/iPhone11-black-1_552x0.png"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 align-self-center">
          <ul>
            <li>Name:APPLE</li>
            <li>Dimensions:THIS ONE</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <h5>Features directive</h3>
      <features
      pics="https://dpyxfisjd0mft.cloudfront.net/lab9-2/system/resized/Shop/Productpages%20-%2010092019/iPhone%2011/iPhone11-black-1_552x0.png"
      name="Iphone"
      dimensions="One"
    ></features>

    <h5>Features directive with some CSS styles</h3>

    <features class="my-features"
      pics="https://dpyxfisjd0mft.cloudfront.net/lab9-2/system/resized/Shop/Productpages%20-%2010092019/iPhone%2011/iPhone11-black-1_552x0.png"
      name="Iphone"
      dimensions="One"
    ></features>

    <h5>Features directive inside a grid</h3>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <features
      pics="https://dpyxfisjd0mft.cloudfront.net/lab9-2/system/resized/Shop/Productpages%20-%2010092019/iPhone%2011/iPhone11-black-1_552x0.png"
      name="Iphone"
      dimensions="One"
    ></features>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```